# MySql query for returning results with starting few letters of a column field

Tags: mysql

I have user table

```
ID   Name

1    Michael
2    Jimmy
```

if i do a query select * from user where name = 'michael'; then it returns row 1, is it possible to do a query with a part of a name, I mean

```
select * from user where name = 'mic';
```

its like the name starts with mic, how can i do a query to return michael row in MySql

Comment: see docu: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) clause and add an appropriate wildcard.

```
select * from user where name like 'mic%'
```

[Wildcards](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

> use “_” to match any single character and “%” to match an arbitrary number of characters (including zero characters)

[Pattern matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

> SQL pattern matching enables you to use “_” to match any single
>   character and “%” to match an arbitrary number of characters
>   (including zero characters). In MySQL, SQL patterns are
>   case-insensitive by default. Some examples are shown here. You do not
>   use = or <> when you use SQL patterns; use the LIKE or NOT LIKE
>   comparison operators instead.

Answer (score 3):

USE LIKE % wildcard

```
select * from user where name like 'mic%';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Select * from user where name like 'mic%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `like`.

```
select * from user where name like 'mic%';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from user where name like 'mic%';
```